# Django display search results

Tags: django, templates, search

I'm currently working on a blog app in Django. As all Blog apps I need a search form. Therefore I have write a small view and context processor (to make the search form available globally) that queries search results:

**view.py:**

```
class BlogSearchListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 10
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Post.objects.published()
        keywords = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if keywords:
            query = SearchQuery(keywords)
            title_vector = SearchVector('title', weight='A')
            content_vector = SearchVector('content', weight='B')
            tag_vector = SearchVector('tag', weight='C')
            vectors = title_vector + content_vector + tag_vector
            qs = qs.annotate(search=vectors).filter(search=query)
            qs = qs.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vectors, query)).order_by('-rank')
        return qs
```

**base.html:**

```
    <div class="globalsearch">
        <form id="searchform" action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <label for="{{ categorysearch_form.category.id_for_label }}">In category: </label>
            {{ categorysearch_form.category }}
            <input class="searchfield" id="searchbox" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search for ...">
            <button class="searchbutton" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**settings.py:**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.core.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'quickblog.quickblog.context_processors.categorysearch_form',
)
```

**context_processors.py**

```
from .forms import PostForm

def categorysearch_form(request):
    form = PostForm()
    return {'categorysearch_form': form}
```

**post_list.html:**

```
{% extends 'quickblog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <h1><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h1>
            <p>{{ post.content|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            <div class="date">
                <a>Published by: {{ post.author }}</a><br>
                <a>Published at: {{ post.published_date }}</a><br>
                <a>Category: {{ post.category }}</a><br>
                <a>Tag(s): {{ post.tag }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <div>
        <span>
         {% if posts.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; First <a> |</a></a>
            <a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
        {% endif %}
        {% if posts.has_next %}
            <span> Page {{ posts.number }} of {{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
            <a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">Next<a> |</a></a>
            <a href="?page={{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}">Last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
       </span>
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The rest of the project can be checked here: https://github.com/rsmvdl/quickblog

I now want to render the results the same way as they get display in my post_list.html view with one detail more: I want that the word the user searched for gets highlighted in the search results, so that the user is able to get the context of the content ASAP ;) . I hope to get any creative ideas. Thanks.

Comment: You can create a custom template tag or filter that inserts an HTML tag around any words you wish to highlight.

Comment: That means also the actual string searched by the user right? Can you give an example at that point?

Comment: I've posted an answer that will hopefully get you started on the right track.

Comment: I first need to find out how to display the actual search results, thats the first point for me. I guess i lost paths here.

Comment: you can use your view's `get_context_data()` function to add anything you need to the context of your template, like your search results.

Comment: Can you give me an example on that? I'm pretty new to all this programing stuff so i need a bit of a template to understand what to change here.

Comment: sorry that wasn't immediately clear from your question. I would start with looking up examples of `get_context_data()` for inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) to add an HTML tag around the searched-for word in your post title or content. This will not be an exact solution but you should be able to adapt it:

```
@register.filter
@stringfilter
def highlight_search_term(text, search_term):
    if search_term in text:
        text.replace(search_term, '<span class="highlight">' + search_term + '</span>')
    return mark_safe(text)
```

You can then apply this filter to your post title or content in your template with `{{ post.title|highlight_search_term:search_term }}`.

You will need to also pass `search_term` to your template context so that the filter can know what to highlight. Be careful with `mark_safe()` if you are applying this to user-submitted content!

Comment: How to pass search_term in a template?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a context processor and pass `request.GET.get('q')` as context.

**context_processors.py**

```
def search(request):
    search_keyword = request.GET.get('q')
    context = {'search_keyword': search_keyword}
    return context
```

And in your template access it as `{{ search_keyword }}`

**search_results.html**

```
<h3>Showing results for: {{ search_keyword }}</h3>
```